# python: how to understand for Boolean expression: a and b not in list

Tags: python, list, if-statement, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

```
def i(obj, x):
    if obj and x not in obj:
        return x
    else:
        return obj

print(i([], 6))
#prints []

def i(obj, x):
    if x and obj not in obj:
        return x
    else:
        return obj

print(i([], 6))
#prints 6
```

how do you formalize the logical expression here?
"obj" and "x" for both case are not in "obj", are they?
if so, how to read correctly these two expressions. I thought they are the same:

```
if obj and x not in obj
if x and obj not in obj
```

Comment: Operator precedence is such that `if obj and x not in obj` means `if (obj) and (x not in obj)` - does that help?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
obj = []
x = 6

if obj and x not in obj
if x and obj not in obj
```

The first conditional. “if Obj” will evaluate to False as the List “obj” is empty. x not in obj will evaluate to true because x is not in the empty list. This line evaluates to false. As False AND True = False

The second line. “if x” will evaluate to true as integers greater than 0 evaluate to true. And “if obj not in obj” will evaluate to true as the obj’s are the same. Technically obj is not in obj. Obj IS THE SAME AS (==) to obj. This TRUE AND TRUE. Evaluates to True.

Difference is how lists vs integers get evaluated as booleans.

To answer your full question the first Boolean ends up with x being returned whereas the second Boolean ends up with obj getting returned.

Comment: " x not in obj will evaluate to true " - It will never get evaluated, as the fist condition is `False`, which is enough to decide that the whole expression is False. Python always short-circuits evaluation in such cases.

Comment: In your answer include also [`operator precedence`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: `obj in obj` is going to be False in most cases: it's unusual for an object to contain itself.  Specifically, `[] in []` is False, and indeed no list can contain itself: there would be an infinite regress.

Comment: Interesting to Note. Didn’t realise Python didn’t evaluate the second condition if the first is false. I think for beginners though it is easier not to consider this and instead look at both halfs of the expression.

Comment: It is actually essential to know, as this is often used to prevent the second part to get evaluated in cases where it could raise an error, such as in `if key in mydict and mydict[key] >42`.

Comment: Ahhhh I see what you mean. I would usually use ```if mydict.get(key) is not None and mydict.get(key) > 42``` but I still see your point. Thinking about this maybe this could even break though. Don’t know what happens for different types other than int. if the value was a dict for example.  Answers lead to more questions ;)

Comment: `if mydict.get(key) is not None and mydict.get(key) > 42`: even this works only because of short-circuit evaluation!  If both parts were evaluated, then a missing key would result in an exception, because the comparison `None > 42` throws a TypeError.

Comment: Also, using `.get` that way is wrong in many cases; it won't distinguish between "key exists and has value `None`" and "key is missing" (if your expectation is that all values are `int`s, then you'd *want* an exception when it turns out a key was inserted with value `None`). As a rule, you only use `.get` when you really *want* the defaulting behavior, not just as a poor man's substitute for actual membership testing.